# Cannot install Logentries Mac Agent on OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, logentries

I tried to install Logentries (Mac Agent) as instructed by [the website](https://logentries.com/doc/mac-agent/) itself. I followed the steps as instructed.

```
 curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/logentries/le/master/install/mac/install.sh
```

I downloaded the install.sh script and ran `sudo ./install.sh`.  But that didn't work so I tried `sudo sh install.sh`.

[image: logentries installing mac agent problem]

When I do `sudo le` then I get same error message as marked in pic above.
I googled but didn't find the solution.

Thank you in advance.

Here is composer.json content

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's missing the formats directory.

sudo pip install formats

should resolve your issue here, then sudo sh install.sh

Comment: I also had to install pip first.
sudo easy_install pip

Answer (score 1):

@user5384112 is correct, the error is being caused by a missing dependancy.

I have a PR to fix this for the Mac installer which should go live shortly.

Comment: FYI this change has gone live. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You can install directly with by downloading with curl or download and install it. You should first look for missing dependencies before installing anything. You should have looked carefully in the documentation and error messages. The error clearly suggests you should have formats. for that do following

```
sudo pip install formats
```